# Strange results using jssc on raspberry-pi

Tags: java, serial-port, raspberry-pi, usb, jssc

I have a raspberry pi connected to a serial-port device using usb-serial cable HL-340 (pl-2303 also tested)

The device takes **1-byte** command and should reply with **2 bytes** (ok, this is very simple device and very easy-to-learn protocol :) )

My code:

```
[...]
        final int[] status = this.serialPort.getLinesStatus ( );
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ( "Lines Status:" );
        final String[] name = new String[] { "CTS", "DSR", "RING", "RLSD" };
        for ( int i = 0; i < status.length; i++ )
          sb.append ( ( i > 0 ) ? "," : "" ).append ( name [i] ).append ( ':' ).append ( status [i] );
        System.out.println ( sb.toString ( ) );
        System.out.println ( "flowcontrol:" + this.serialPort.getFlowControlMode ( ) );
        this.serialPort.purgePort ( SerialPort.PURGE_RXCLEAR | SerialPort.PURGE_TXCLEAR );

        synchronized ( this )
        {
          System.out.println ( "1) getInputBufferBytesCount():" + this.serialPort.getInputBufferBytesCount ( ) );
          this.serialPort.addEventListener ( this );
          this.serialPort.setEventsMask ( SerialPort.MASK_RXCHAR );
          this.serialPort.writeBytes ( COMMAND );
          wait ( 3000 ); // wait 3 seconds for reply
          this.serialPort.removeEventListener ( );
          System.out.println ( "2) getInputBufferBytesCount():" + this.serialPort.getInputBufferBytesCount ( ) );
          final int n = this.serialPort.getInputBufferBytesCount ( );
          if ( n > 0 )
          {
            this.serialPort.readBytes ( n ); // purge garbage data?
            System.out.println ( "3) getInputBufferBytesCount():" + this.serialPort.getInputBufferBytesCount ( ) );
          }
        }  
        if ( ( this.data == null ) && ( this.error == null ) )
          this.error = "no response from device";
[...]
```

and the callback code:

```
@Override
public final void serialEvent ( final SerialPortEvent event )
{
  synchronized ( this )
  {
    try
    {
      final int val;
      if ( event.isRXCHAR ( ) )
        if ( (val = event.getEventValue ( )) == 2 ) // the reply is 2 bytes
          this.data = this.serialPort.readBytes ( 2 );
        else
          this.error = "unexpected value:" + val;
      else
        this.error = "unexpected event:" + event;
    }
    catch ( final Throwable x )
    {
      this.error = x.toString ( );
    }
    finally
    {
      notify ( );
    }
  }
}
```

**The results are very strange and unpredictable** :( I expect only 2 bytes as a reply from the device, but serial port notifies me much more data available for reading:

```
Lines Status:CTS:0,DSR:0,RING:0,RLSD:0
flowcontrol:0
1) getInputBufferBytesCount():0
2) getInputBufferBytesCount():544
3) getInputBufferBytesCount():0
java.lang.Throwable: unexpected value:192
```

or

```
Lines Status:CTS:0,DSR:0,RING:0,RLSD:0
flowcontrol:0
1) getInputBufferBytesCount():0
2) getInputBufferBytesCount():512
3) getInputBufferBytesCount():0
java.lang.Throwable: unexpected value:192
```

or

```
Lines Status:CTS:0,DSR:0,RING:0,RLSD:0
flowcontrol:0
1) getInputBufferBytesCount():0
2) getInputBufferBytesCount():32
3) getInputBufferBytesCount():0
java.lang.Throwable: unexpected value:32
```

**What is a problem? Which port settings should I change?**

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you were waiting for 2 bytes reply, now after that reply have been received print all the bytes in buffer to see if this is junk data (special non-printable characters) or valid data. This will give you more insight and next action item to progress further.